# Tokenize in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split, tokenize

If I have a string, how can I split it into an array of words and filter out some stopwords? I only want words of length 2 or greater.

If my string is

```
var text = "This is a short text about StackOverflow.";
```

I can split it with

```
var words = text.split(/\W+/);
```

But using `split(/\W+/)`, I get all words. I could check if the words have a length of at least 2 with

```
function validate(token) {
  return /\w{2,}/.test(token);
}
```

but I guess I could do this smarter/faster with regexp.

I also have an array `var stopwords = ['has', 'have', ...]` which shouldn't be allowed in the array.

Actually, if I can find a way to filter out stopwords, I could just add all letters a, b, c, ..., z to the stopwords array to only accept words with at least 2 characters.

Comment: This can be easily done using arrays and filter methods, are you looking to do all this with regex instead?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with `text.split(/\W+/).filter(validate)`. No need to write an overcomplicated regex.

Comment: You can get rid of non-word symbols and all words that are less than 1 in length with `text.split(/\W+|\b\w\b/)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do what you started: split by `/W+/` and then validate each token (length and stopwords) in the array by using [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var text = "This is a short text about StackOverflow.";
var stopwords = ['this'];

var words = text.split(/\W+/).filter(function(token) {
    token = token.toLowerCase();
    return token.length >= 2 && stopwords.indexOf(token) == -1;
});

console.log(words); // ["is", "short", "text", "about", "StackOverflow"]
```

You could easily tweak a regex to look for words `>= 2` characters, but there's no point if you're already going to need to post-process to remove stopwords (`token.length` will be faster than any fancy regex you write).

Answer (score 2):

Easy with Ramda:

```
var text       = "This is a short text about how StackOverflow has gas.";
var stopWords  = ['have', 'has'];
var isLongWord = R.compose(R.gt(R.__, 2), R.length);
var isGoWord   = R.compose(R.not, R.contains(R.__, stopWords));
var tokenize   = R.compose(R.filter(isGoWord), R.filter(isLongWord), R.split(' '));

tokenize(text); // ["This", "short", "text", "about", "how", "StackOverflow", "gas."]
```

http://bit.ly/1V5bVrP

Answer (score 1):

What about splitting on something like this if you want to use a pure regex approach:

```
\W+|\b\w{1,2}\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/rB4cJ4/1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function filterArray(a, num_words, stop_words) {
    b = [];
    for (var ct = 0; ct <= a.length - 1; ct++) {
        if (!(a[ct] <= num_words) && !ArrayContains[a[ct], stop_words) {
            b.push(a[ct]);
        }
    }
    return b
}
function ArrayContains(word, a) {
    for (var ct = 0; ct <= a.length - 1; ct++) {
        if (word == a[ct]) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

var words = "He walks the dog";
var stops = ["dog"]
var a = words.split(" ");
var f = filterArray(a, 2, stops);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be help

```
(?:\b\W*\w\W*\b)+|\W+
```

output:

Thisis`a`shorttextaboutStackOverflow`. A..Z`abc`..`xyz`.`

where  is matched string.